# I have some issue with ObservableCollection, in my list there are values added but they are not showing in my list view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This is the code i have written so far, the ObservableCollection list is populated with string values but the list view won't show the text. Is there something aim missing or doing wrong? I would be really happy if anyone could give me some reply on this!

```
public class interactiveListViewCode : ContentPage
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; }


    public interactiveListViewCode()
    {

        items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { };
        //List<string> items = new List<string>();
        ListView lstView = new ListView();
        lstView.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;
        //lstView.Refreshing += OnRefresh;
        lstView.ItemSelected += OnSelection;
        lstView.ItemTapped += OnTap;
        lstView.ItemsSource = items;
        var temp = new DataTemplate(typeof(textViewCell));
        lstView.ItemTemplate = temp;
        Content = lstView;
    }

    internal void insertComanyName(String[] companyName, String[] idForCompany)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < companyName.Length; i++)
        {
            string temp;
            temp = companyName[i];
            items.Add(temp);
            Debug.WriteLine("this is in the items List " + items[i]);
        }

    }
```

And also this is the "textViewCell" class:

public class textViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        public textViewCell()
        {
            StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
            layout.Padding = new Thickness(15, 0);
            Label label = new Label();

```
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        layout.Children.Add(label);

        var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = "More" };
        moreAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
        moreAction.Clicked += OnMore;

        var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background
        deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
        deleteAction.Clicked += OnDelete;

        this.ContextActions.Add(moreAction);
        this.ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);
        View = layout;
    }
```

Comment: It seems right to me. Can you share the code of your "textViewCell" class?

Comment: Your `DataTemplate` is empty - I'd suggest you read some examples. It's a lot easier to create a `DataTemplate` declaratively in XAML than in code.

Comment: Sure! Here is my "textviewCell" class:

Comment: Does your code work when using just a regular `TextCell`?

Comment: Where's the call to insertComanyName? I think it's not being called. 
Your code seems just like the InteractivityListView sample. :)

Comment: It is the InteractivityListView sample, iam new to program layouts and stuff like that and trying to learn:). But I think the problem is the binding in the "textViewCell" class, I don't know how to bind my list with the new binding() object

Comment: I have solved this issue and i have made a new data template! if you want to see how i solved it just comment and i will post it here:)